# sqlalchemy MSSQL+pyodbc schema none

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to connect to SQL server 2019 via sqlalchemy. I'm using both mssql+pyodbc and msql+pyodbc_mssql, but on both cases it cannot connect, always returns default_schema_name not defined.
Already checked database, user schema defined and everything.

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
server = 'server' 
database = 'db' 
username = 'user' 
password = 'pass' 
#cnxn = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Trusted_Connection=yes'
cnxn = 'DSN=SQL Server;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Trusted_Connection=yes'
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(cnxn)

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)
cnxn = engine.connect()
```

> return None, dialect.default_schema_name
> AttributeError: 'MSDialect_pyodbc' object has no attribute 'default_schema_name'

TIA.....

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: nope. Apparently the dialect for SQL server is not correct, it does not work.

Comment: I did eventually get this setup working, want me to post an answer?

Comment: Would love to. I tried many ways, sqlalchemy seems to never talk correctly to SQL server 2019.

Comment: Righto, example posted below. Taken from a working script. The best tip is also to make sure you have the Microsoft ODBC drivers for SQL server installed, not just pyodbc. Version 17 worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the following provides enough for a minimum viable sample. I'm using it in a larger script to move 12m rows 3x a day, and for that reason I've included an example of chunking that I pinched from elsewhere.

```
#Set up enterprise DB connection
# Enterprise DB to be used
DRIVER = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
USERNAME = "SQLUsername"
PSSWD = "SQLPassword"
SERVERNAME = "SERVERNAME01"
INSTANCENAME = "\SQL_01"
DB = "DATABASE_Name"
TABLE = "Table_Name"

#Set up SQL database connection variable / path
#I have included this as an example that can be used to chunk data up
conn_executemany = sql.create_engine(
    f"mssql+pyodbc://{USERNAME}:{PSSWD}@{SERVERNAME}{INSTANCENAME}/{DB}?driver={DRIVER}", fast_executemany=True
)




#Used for SQL Loading from Pandas DF
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos : pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

#Used for SQL Loading from Pandas DF
def insert_with_progress(df, engine, table="", schema="dbo"):
    con = engine.connect()

    # Replace table
    #engine.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {schema}.{table};") #This only works for SQL Server 2016 or greater
    try:
      engine.execute(f"DROP TABLE Temp_WeatherGrids;")
    except:
      print("Unable to drop temp table")
    
    try:
      engine.execute(f"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp_WeatherGrids]([col_01] [int] NULL,[Location] [int] NULL,[DateTime] [datetime] NULL,[Counts] [real] NULL) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];")
    except:
      print("Unable to create temp table")
    

    # Insert with progress
    SQL_SERVER_CHUNK_LIMIT = 250000
    chunksize = math.floor(SQL_SERVER_CHUNK_LIMIT / len(df.columns))

    for chunk in chunker(df, chunksize):
        chunk.to_sql(
            name=table,
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # intialise data. Example -  make your own dataframe. DateTime should be pandas datetime objects. 
    data = {'Col_01':[0, 1, 2, 3], 
            'Location':['Bar', 'Pub', 'Brewery', 'Bottleshop'],
            'DateTime':["1/1/2018", "1/1/2019", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2021"],
            'Counts':[1, 2, 3, 4} 
  
    # Create DataFrame 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

    insert_with_progress(df, conn_executemany, table=TABLE)
    del [df]
```